# Balls and Spheres in $(n; k; c)$-expander.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V;E)$ be an $(n; k; c)$-expander. Let $v\in V$ be a vertex of $X$, and $r$ a non-negative integer. The ball of radius $r$ centered at $v$ is define to be
$$B_r(v) = \{w \in V \mid d(v;w) \leq r\}$$

Let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be some vertices in $G$, and let $d(v_1,v_2)=d$; we define 2 balls, $B_r(v_1)$ and $B_r(v_2)$ such that $r=d/2$.

I know that $$B_r(v_1) \cap B_r(v_2) = 1$$

but I try to find the number of vertex that are in $B_{r+1}(v_1)$ and $B_{r+1}(v_2)$,
meaning $$ B_{r+1}(v_1) ∩ B_{r+1}(v_2) = ??$$

Definition ($c$–expander)- we say that a graph $G= (V;E)~$ is an $c$–expander if for every set $|S|\leq n/2$, we have that $\frac{|\partial(S)|}{|S|}\ge c$ for a real number $c >0~$. An $(n,c,k)$-expander is a graph such that each vertex has degree $k$ and it is a $c$–expander.

Comment: What is an $(n; k; c)$-expander? It is also unclear what you are trying to say with $$d(v_1,v_2)=d,\ B_r(v_1), \ B_r(v_2),\ 2r=d$$ I suppose you mean "let $d = d(v_1, v_2)$ and let $r = \frac d2$", but what is the reason for listing the two sets separated by commas between them? And it is the size $|B_r(v_1) ∩ B_r(v_2)| = 1$, not the intersection itself. Lastly, using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) will help immensely in attracting useful answers.

Comment: this is the definition to expander - we say that a graph G= (V;E) is an c–expander if for every set S≤n/2, we have that -   |∂(S)||S|≥c    real number c >0 An (n,c,k)-expander is a graph that each vertex has degree k and he is a c–expander. there is no reason for listing the two sets separated by commas between them. i try to understand the amount of joined vertex between the tow balls

Comment: What is $n$? The number of vertices in $G$?

Comment: n is the number of vertices in G

Comment: FYI - to get braces to show in MathJax, you have to escape them: `$\{w \in V \mid d(v;w) \le r\}$` shows $\{w \in V \mid d(v;w) \le r\}$. Another useful trick: if you see something in MathJax and want to know how it was produced, right-click on it and select "Show Math As > TeX Commands", and it will open a dialog with the mark-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue when $d$ is odd. Then $r$ is not an integer and the two balls do not intersect. For example, in the simple graph $v_1 - \cdot - \cdot - v_2$, $d = 3, r = 1.5$ and each of the balls is just the center and immediate neighbor.

---

If $d$ is even, then it is true that $$\left|B_r(v_1) \cap B_r(v_2)\right| \ge 1$$
But I see nothing in your conditions that would require it to actually be $1$. There could be multiple paths of length $d$ connecting $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Let $N_r = B_r(v_1) \cap B_r(v_2)$.  $N_r \subseteq N_{r+1}$, so $|N_{r+1}| \ge |N_r|$. Also for any $v \in N_r$ all $k$ of its neighbors must be in $N_{r+1}$. But some of those neighbors can be other vertices in $N_r$, so they doesn't necessarily increase the size of $N_{r+1}$. Any single vertex in $N_r$ guarantees $k+1$ vertices (itself and its $k$ neighbors) in $N_{r+1}$, so we are guaranteed that $|N_{r+1}| \ge {k+1}$, but those two requirements is all you can guarantee.
$$|N_{r+1}| \ge \max\{k+1, |N_r|\}$$

But that is the best you can do for a lower bound. I do not see how being a $c$-expander would change this, as the requirements could be met elsewhere than in the intersection fo the two balls.

You can get an upper limit by supposing that no two elements of $N_r$ share any neighbors. This assures that the $k+1$ points of intersection in $N_{r+1}$ guaranteed by each element of $N_r$ do not overlap. But there can be other new points of intersection. If there were non-intersection points on the boundary of the $r$-radius balls that were within a distance $\le 2$ of each other, those points generate new intersections for the balls of radius $r+1$. And assuming that every point on the boundary of $B_r(v_1)$ that is not in $N_r$ has only one connection to the interior, and the other $k-1$ neighbors are all in $N_{r+1}$, this gives a maximum of $(k-1)|\partial B_r(v_1) \setminus N_r|$ new intersection points. And similarly for $v_2$, except that the new intersection points for each must be the same. This means
$$\begin{align}\max\{k+1, |N_r|\} \le &|N_{r+1}| \le (k+1)|N_r| + (k-1)\min\{|\partial B_r(v_1)|-|N_r|, |\partial B_r(v_2)|-|N_r|\}\\\\\max\{k+1, |N_r|\} \le &|N_{r+1}| \le 2|N_r|+ (k-1)\min\{|\partial B_r(v_1)|, |\partial B_r(v_2)|\}\end{align}$$

In this, I haven't made any use of the $c$-expander property, but I don't think it will make much of a difference.

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer. we can us the expander in order to find $|∂Br(v1)|$ and $|∂Br(v2)|$, i know how to continue from, here